# Application crashing because of NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I'm working with a listview which on click opens a dialog box which contains an edittext and a button. On button click, the value entered in the editText is saved in a textView from listview item which had been pressed before. The problem is that the value wasn't saved anymore if I reopened the application. I tried to make it save using sharedPrefences but it's crashing and shows 3 nullpointerexception and can't deal with them.

Here is my:

**Carnet.java**

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Carnet extends TabActivity {
    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String NOTA_SPEC = "Note";
    private static final String ABSENTE_SPEC = "Absente";
    private static final String MEDII_SPEC = "Medii";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.carnet);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabSpec NotaSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(NOTA_SPEC);
        // Tab Icon
        NotaSpec.setIndicator(NOTA_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nota_open));
        Intent notaIntent = new Intent(this, Note.class);
        // Tab Content
        NotaSpec.setContent(notaIntent);


        TabSpec AbsenteSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(ABSENTE_SPEC);
        AbsenteSpec.setIndicator(ABSENTE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nota_open));
        Intent absenteIntent = new Intent(this, Absente.class);
        AbsenteSpec.setContent(absenteIntent);

        TabSpec MediiSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(MEDII_SPEC);
        AbsenteSpec.setIndicator(MEDII_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nota_open));
        Intent mediiIntent = new Intent(this, MediiL.class);
        AbsenteSpec.setContent(mediiIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(NotaSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(AbsenteSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(MediiSpec);

    }
}
```

**Note.java**

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Note extends Activity {

    private static final ListAdapter NoteAdapter = null;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<?> prgmName;
    TextView text;

    public static String[] prgmNameList = { "Romana   - ", "Matematica   - ",
            "Lb. Engleza   - ", "Lb. Germana/Franceza - ", "Istorie   - ",
            "Geografie   - ", "Biologie   - ", "Fizica   - ", "Ed. Fizica   - " };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_listview);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        context = this;

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

        // Variable is public for clarity.
        String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(adapter.savedEntries);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LV Data",
                MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("TVEntries", toSave);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LV Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String encoded = prefs.getString("TVEntries", "");

        String[] entries;
        if (encoded.equals(""))
            entries = null;
        else
            entries = EncodeDecode.decode(encoded);

        NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
        adapter.savedEntries = entries;
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

And **NoteAdapter.java:**

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] result;
    Context context;
    int[] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Dialog dialog;
    String[] savedEntries;
    String[] saved = null;

    public NoteAdapter(Note note, String[] saved, String[] prgmNameList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result = prgmNameList;
        context = note;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (saved == null) {
            savedEntries = new String[result.length];
            Arrays.fill(savedEntries, "");
        } else
            savedEntries = saved;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return savedEntries[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
        public TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.setTitle("Materie:" + result[position]);

                final EditText txtMode = (EditText) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.dialog);
                Button btnSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bsave);

                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String data = txtMode.getText().toString();
                        holder.text.setText(data);

                        savedEntries[position] = data;

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("data", data);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }

        });
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

**logcat:**

```
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419): Process: com.cngcnasaud.orar, PID: 1419
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cngcnasaud.orar/com.cngcnasaud.orar.Carnet}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cngcnasaud.orar/com.cngcnasaud.orar.Note}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cngcnasaud.orar/com.cngcnasaud.orar.Note}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2035)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:240)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at com.cngcnasaud.orar.Carnet.onCreate(Carnet.java:45)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     ... 11 more
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at com.cngcnasaud.orar.NoteAdapter.getCount(NoteAdapter.java:46)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at com.cngcnasaud.orar.Note.onCreate(Note.java:34)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-18 19:27:28.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1419):     ... 21 more
```

**Carnet.java line 45:**

```
tabHost.addTab(NotaSpec);
```

**NoteAdapter.java line 46:**

```
return result.length;
```

**Note.java line 34:**

```
 lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your String array in null here:

*NoteAdapter.java line 46:*

```
return result.length;
```

because is a class field, you populate in the constructor from a parameter:

```
public NoteAdapter(Note note, String[] saved, String[] prgmNameList) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result = prgmNameList;
```

that you pass as null here (passed as second parameter, it should be third):

*Note.java line 34:*

```
lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null));
```

There is no point in passing that as a parameter as it is a public constant (public static final).

Comment: This is working.. but now I get nullpointerexception here: holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]); .. line 76 in NoteAdapter.java . Thanks a lot !

Comment: I guess it is text variable (the TextView object) which is null.

Comment: The array shouldn't have been populated. It will be populated by the user later. When the app starts, the TextView should be null, and only after users enter values, it should be filled with that values. How to fix it?

Comment: You will have to debug line by line to catch this, or try to restrict that problem and ask another question on stackoverflow.